# Find number based on modulo conditions

Tags: python, math

I need to upgrade my code and I need to add function to find a number divided by 7, and getting modulo from 2,3,4,5,6 = 1.

I wrote that code:

```
a = 0
while a != 1:
    x = 0
    if(x % 2 == 1 and x % 3 == 1 and x % 4 == 1 and x % 5 == 1 and x % 6 == 1
       and x % 7 == 0) == True:
        a = 1
        print(x)
    else:
        a = 1
        x = x+1
```

I need to find first number divided by 7 and get all modulo from 2 to 6 ==1

Comment: I am a bit confused, what is it you want to do? Find the first number divided by 7 then getting the modulo of 2 to 6?

Comment: yeah, getting modulo 2-6 == 1 :C

Comment: "C" isn't a number, it's a letter of the alphabet. It's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you're asking. From reading the code, I think you're trying to find the first number that is divisible by 2-6 but not by 7, right?

Comment: @martineau :C is an emoticon ;)

Comment: martin: Does the code you have work and you want to know a better way to do it, or does it not work and you want to know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is a while loop `while a != 1`.

However, regardless of what happens (your number `x` meets the criteria or not), `a` is immediately set to 1, meaning that after only 1 run, your loop will immediately end.

Furthermore, since `x=0` at the start of any run of the loop, `x` will never meet your criteria.

Try re-designing your algorithm, because the way you're getting your number doesn't work at all.

Personally, I'd suggest using a `while True`, and you don't need `a`, only `x`.

Here's what I wrote

```py
x = 0
while True:
    if(x % 2 == 1 and x % 3 == 1 and x % 4 == 1 and x % 5 == 1 and x % 6 == 1 and x % 7 == 0):
        print(x)
        break
    x += 1
```

The first number I got was 301.

Comment: Shorter: `if all(x % i == 1 for i in range(2, 7)) and x % 7 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through multiples of 7 and check the condition while doing so, you can use `all()` to check for those conditions as the following:

```
i = 7
while True:
    if all(i%x==1 for x in range(2, 7)):
        print(x)
        break
    i += 7
```